# Kubernetes Service with externalTrafficPolicy: Local and Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Help me find problem.
When I use `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` in K8s Service I lost part of my requests.

On every worker node(3 nodes) I have ingress controller:

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE    IP                NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
ingress-nginx-admission-create-ftw46        0/1     Completed   0          3h8m   192.168.186.218   node03   <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-29gbc         0/1     Completed   1          3h8m   192.168.140.81    node02   <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx-controller-66479f6d78-6rbkv   1/1     Running     0          18m    192.168.196.158   node01   <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx-controller-66479f6d78-gh4bv   1/1     Running     0          18m    192.168.186.226   node03   <none>           <none>
ingress-nginx-controller-66479f6d78-qwxzq   1/1     Running     0          18m    192.168.140.90    node02   <none>           <none>
```

Service with nodePort for incoming traffic:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.4.0
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - appProtocol: http
    name: http
    port: 80
    nodePort: 10080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https
    port: 443
    nodePort: 10443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: NodePort
```

Making request to one of the node I get result as this one. Part of request if timeout:

```
curl -H "Host:my.kubia.local" 192.168.56.23:10080
You've hit kubia-z7slg

curl -H "Host:my.kubia.local" 192.168.56.23:10080
You've hit kubia-pjgtc

curl -H "Host:my.kubia.local" 192.168.56.23:10080
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.56.23 port 10080 after 75012 ms: Operation timed out

curl -H "Host:my.kubia.local" 192.168.56.23:10080
You've hit kubia-z7slg

curl -H "Host:my.kubia.local" 192.168.56.23:10080
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.56.23 port 10080 after 75012 ms: Operation timed out
```

Ingress manifest:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: my.nginx.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port: 
              number: 8080
  - host: my.kubia.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubia
            port: 
              number: 80
```

If I delete externalTrafficPolicy: Local  option all requests will be successful.

I tried use ingress controller as Deployment with replicas on all node and DaemonSet. Result the same.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `externalTrafficPolicy`?

Comment: to preserve the source IP

Comment: nginx-ingress adds the source IP in the x-forwarded-for header by default. Do not need externalTrafficPolicy for that.

Comment: That's workarount, thanks. But I'm interested in finding the reason for the timeout.

Comment: nginx-ingress add node IP in the x-forwarded-for not source IP ((

Comment: ```User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
X-Forwarded-For: 10.0.2.15
X-Forwarded-Host: my.echo.local
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-Scheme: https
X-Real-Ip: 10.0.2.15
X-Request-Id: 34c3a5dfdaa61f0b8759a1f6ac8c2602
X-Scheme: https``` where 10.0.2.15 node IP, not client IP